# JavaFX webview encoding

Tags: java, jquery, user-interface, javafx

I'm showing a website with JavaFX webview. In that page there are elements made with Jquery UI and all labels (Buttons, Tabs, etc…) that are created by Jquery have a false encoding. 
Plain Text is encoded right. 
When I view that webpage in a real browser everything just works fine. The character encoding is set in the http header as well as in the  part to utf-8.

Actually I really don't know where to start debugging. The website works fine and the JavaFX webview works well with other websites.

Answer (score 0):

Try to embed jQuery to webview component.

> Link :https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3077942